# MainActivity must implement AlertPositiveListener

Tags: java, android, radio-button, android-alertdialog

I trying to create a `showAddForm` button like the image below.

[image]

When the + button is clicked,  alert Dialog window with radio buttons will be shown.

**Claims.java**

```
public class Claims extends Fragment  {
    Intent intent;
    int position=0;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View claims= inflater.inflate(R.layout.claims, container, false);
        View.OnClickListener listener =new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                FragmentManager manager =getFragmentManager();
                AlertDialogRadio alert = new AlertDialogRadio();
                /** Creating a bundle object to store the selected item's index */
                Bundle b  = new Bundle();

                /** Storing the selected item's index in the bundle object */
                b.putInt("position", position);

                /** Setting the bundle object to the dialog fragment object */
                alert.setArguments(b);

                /** Creating the dialog fragment object, which will in turn open the alert dialog window */
                alert.show(manager, "alert_dialog_radio");
            }
        };
        Button button1=(Button)claims.findViewById(R.id.button10);
        Button button=(Button)claims.findViewById(R.id.button8);
       button1.setOnClickListener(listener);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), CameraMain.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return claims;
    }
}
```

**AlertDialogRadio.java**

```
public class AlertDialogRadio extends DialogFragment {
    /** Declaring the interface, to invoke a callback function in the implementing activity class */
    AlertPositiveListener alertPositiveListener;

    /** An interface to be implemented in the hosting activity for "OK" button click listener */
    interface AlertPositiveListener {
        public void onPositiveClick(int position);
    }

    /** This is a callback method executed when this fragment is attached to an activity.
     *  This function ensures that, the hosting activity implements the interface AlertPositiveListener
     * */
    public void onAttach(android.app.Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try{
            alertPositiveListener = (AlertPositiveListener) activity;
        }catch(ClassCastException e){
            // The hosting activity does not implemented the interface AlertPositiveListener
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement AlertPositiveListener");
        }
    }

    /** This is the OK button listener for the alert dialog,
     *  which in turn invokes the method onPositiveClick(position)
     *  of the hosting activity which is supposed to implement it
     */
    OnClickListener positiveListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            AlertDialog alert = (AlertDialog)dialog;
            int position = alert.getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();
            alertPositiveListener.onPositiveClick(position);
        }
    };

    /** This is a callback method which will be executed
     *  on creating this fragment
     */
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        /** Getting the arguments passed to this fragment */
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        int position = bundle.getInt("position");

        /** Creating a builder for the alert dialog window */
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        /** Setting a title for the window */
        b.setTitle("Choose your version");

        /** Setting items to the alert dialog */
        b.setSingleChoiceItems(Android.code, position, null);

        /** Setting a positive button and its listener */
        b.setPositiveButton("OK",positiveListener);

        /** Setting a positive button and its listener */
        b.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

        /** Creating the alert dialog window using the builder class */
        AlertDialog d = b.create();

        /** Return the alert dialog window */
        return d;
    }
}
```

**Android.java**

```
public class Android {

    static String[] code = new String[]{
            "Project",
            "Petrol",
            "Medical",

    };
}
```

Unfortunately, when the + button is clicked, the app crashed.

**LogCat Error**

```
10-24 23:18:19.500    9033-9033/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project.project, PID: 9033
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.project.project.MainActivity@422ab848 must implement AlertPositiveListener
            at com.example.project.project.AlertDialogRadio.onAttach(AlertDialogRadio.java:31)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:849)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1453)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
```

**Edited**

[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> MainActivity@422ab848 must implement AlertPositiveListener

Because `MainActivity` or `Claims` Fragment both not implementing  `AlertPositiveListener` interface but trying to cast `Activity`  to `AlertPositiveListener`.

Either implement `AlertPositiveListener` in `MainActivity` or best is implement in `Claims` Fragment because if want to get callback in Fragment from which showing `DialogFragment`.

**1.** implement `AlertPositiveListener` in `Claims` Fragment:

```
  public class Claims extends Fragment  implement AlertPositiveListener{ 

     .....
   }
```

**2.** Create a setListener method in  `AlertDialogRadio` Fragment :

```
public void setListener(AlertPositiveListener alertPositiveListener){
 this.alertPositiveListener=alertPositiveListener;
}
```

**3.** Call `setListener` from `Claims` Fragment:

```
AlertDialogRadio alert = new AlertDialogRadio();
alert.setListener(this);
```

and also declare `AlertPositiveListener` interface as `public`

Comment: how to declare AlertPositiveListener interface as public? like what I did in the AlertDialogRadio?

Comment: @Hoo: do it as `public  interface AlertPositiveListener`. if not working then best is make `AlertPositiveListener` interface in separate file

Comment: @Hoo: add `public` before ` interface AlertPositiveListener` and use ` AlertDialogRadio.AlertPositiveListener`

Comment: did u mean public class Claims extends Fragment implements AlertDialogRadio.AlertPositiveListener{???

Comment: @Hoo: Yes and also use `public interface AlertPositiveListener {
        public void onPositiveClick(int position);
    }`

Comment: class claims must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onPositiveClick(int)...'

Comment: @Hoo: move `AlertPositiveListener` in separate file then try it

Comment: What should I put in the  separate file ?

Comment: @Hoo: In same way as you have created ` AlertDialogRadio` file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93255/discussion-between-hoo-and--k).

Comment: So the issue was related to the Implementation of the MainActivity class. It had to implement the AlertPositiveListener and it worked

Answer (score 0):

The Activity where the `AlertDialogRadio` fragment is attached must implement the mentioned interface.

This is forced in your `AlertDialogRadio` fragment code:

```
public void onAttach(android.app.Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try{
        alertPositiveListener = (AlertPositiveListener) activity;
    }catch(ClassCastException e){
        // The hosting activity does not implemented the interface AlertPositiveListener
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement AlertPositiveListener");
    }
}
```

To fix this, add `implements AlertPositiveListener` to your activity and implement the callback methods